# How I can find controller at the start page

Tags: magento-1.9

How I can find controller at the start page, if my url is without some path. Just example.loc?

Comment: why do you need controler? Do you want to edit content of the homepage?

Comment: @K.Maliszewski yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Controller for homepage is `Mage_Cms_IndexController`.